# Customising Google i'm not a robot recaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, css, validation, recaptcha

Need to customize css for google recaptcha. Also need to know about client side validation. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This is validation function

```
function get_action(form)
{
    var g = document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha');
    var v = grecaptcha.getResponse(g-recaptcha);
    if(v.length == 0)
    {
       document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="*You can't leave Captcha Code empty ";
       return false;
    }
    if(v.length != 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="                   ";
        return true; 
    }
}
```

call above function from your form.

put this div where you want place recaptcha and span for display error message

Answer (score 1):

`ReCaptcha` Supports variety of themes, Some of them are listed below.

```
red
white
blackglass
clean
custom
```

The red, white, blackglass, and clean themes are pre-defined themes where reCAPTCHA provides the user interface. In the custom theme, your site has full control over the reCAPTCHA appearance.

Apply it like this way

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'custom',
    custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
 };
 </script>
```

What are the `id` and `classes` used by `recaptcha`

1. An empty div with ID recaptcha_image. This is where the actual image
   will be placed. The div will be 300x57 pixels.
2. A text input with ID and name both set to recaptcha_response_field.
   This is where the user can enter their answer.
3. Optionally, a div which contains the entire reCAPTCHA widget. This
   ID div should be placed into the custom_theme_widget and the style
   of the div should be set to display:none. After the reCAPTCHA
   theming code has fully loaded, it will make the div visible. This
   element avoids making the page flicker while it loads.

**Moreover**

Google has complete documentation on how to style recaptcha forms here:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

and you can completely override the html/css they provide with your own.